# Image not rendering in html. (<img>)

Tags: html, css

I believe my files are located in the same folder but for some reason it's just not working. Here is the screen shot of my folder. [The screen shot of my folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdOej.png)

And here is the code... (The code is in index.html shown in the screen shot.)

```
<div>
  <img src="Tawsk.jpg" alt="Tawsk" width="460" height="345">
</div>
```

I don't know what the problem is... It will be great if you could provide me with some guidance. Thanks.

Comment: `img src="./Tawsk.jpg"`

Comment: Thanks for replying. I just tried what you said but it's still not working... :(

Comment: Oh wow you are right. I got an error. I have been using Django in the back end and that seemed to be the problem. This is the error I got, "The current path, Tawsk.jpg, didn’t match any of these". Anyways now I know the problem and I was told to go set DEBUG = False in settings.py so I did but then I got another error saying; You must set settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS if DEBUG is False. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Never mind I fixed it. All good

Answer (score 2):

you forget some syntax to write "./" on your code

```html
<div>
  <img src="./Tawsk.jpg" alt="Tawsk" width="460" height="345">
</div>
```